# Weird encoding in image files after copy to another drive

Tags: file-transfer, encoding, copy

After copying some image files to a new drive (including jpg, psd and tif), none of them can be opened anymore. Checking the code, I see there's weird encoding, something like this:

[image]

The same goes for all formats (even psd files, that usually have a lot of readable information at header).

I suppose it's an encoding error, but trying to change it from ANSI to UTF and others using Notepad++ doesn't help. Any idea what happened and how can I recover those files?

*Edit: Windows 10, disk not encrypted, no readable data in both ends of the file.*

Comment: Title says "... after copy..." but question starts "After moving..." - so which one you did, and how exactly? Since you're using NP++ I'm assuming this is in Windows? There's nothing sensible at the end of the file either? Is the disk you moved them to perhaps encrypted? Please update the question instead of answering on a comment.

Comment: 1) Encoding does not come into it when it's a binary file, such as jpg, psd, and tif. Changing the "encoding" in such files is expected to destroy them. 2) How did you transfer the files: was it through FTP set to text mode, by any chance?

Comment: 3) It would be better to use a hex editor to inspect such files, e.g. [Use Notepad++ as HEX-Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60727840/1115360).